# How to find dependent materialized query table

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw

Is there a simple way to find out which materialized query tables use my table say mytable.

As i could not alter the table because it is a base table for a materialized query table.

Comment: Which OS? Are you looking for a command or are you usng a GUI like Data Studio?

Comment: Linux, i am looking for a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be queried via the System Catalog like this:

```
select TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
  from syscat.tabdep
 where DTYPE = 'S'
   and BSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' 
   and BNAME = 'EMPLOYEE'
```

More details about the columns can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001067.html).

Comment: Thanks it helped to find the  dependent materialized query tables